# how to remove base model name and its associated model name from find method in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am retrieving data from the database with the help of belong to association using find method in cakephp. It's work perfectly but getting output like `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PaymentLine] => Array
                (
                    [Amount] => -1000.000
                    [OpenAmount] => -1000.000
                    [Narration] => 
                )
            [Payment] => Array
                (
                    [TXNName] => Receipt-1
                    [TXNDate] => 2014-08-06
                )
        )
)`
But I have to arrange data like `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Amount] => -1000.000
            [OpenAmount] => -1000.000
            [Narration] => 
            [TXNName] => Receipt-1
            [TXNDate] => 2014-08-06
        )
)`

For these purpose I used Set::ClassicExtract method but that method not working for me... please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to simply loop over the collection that is returned by the find method?

Perhaps try doing something like this:

```
$values = [];

foreach($array_of_arrays as $key => $array)
{
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        $values[] = $value;
    }
}
```

$values will then contain all the values. The end result that you listed is not really possible to achieve if I understand what you are trying to do. This is because in that example you have duplicate keys for things such as 'id' and 'created'. If you only want to get the Arrays and store them in an array without the key then all you have to do is use:

```
array_values($array_of_arrays);
```

which will return the array but with the inner arrays having numeric keys instead of the enum ones.

If (for example) you had stored your data that you are getting back in a array called $dummy_data it would look something like this:

```
$dummy_data = [
'Profile' => Array
    (
        'id' => "12",
        'user_id' => "121",
        'skill' => "Baking Cakes",
        'created' => "2007-05-01 10:31:01"
    ),
'User' => Array
    (
        'id' => "121",
        'name' => "Gwoo the Kungwoo",
        'created' => "2007-05-01 10:31:01"
        )
];
```

If you know for a fact that the created values will always be the same for the 'Profile' and 'User' arrays then you can get a final array by using

`array_merge($dummy_data['User'], $dummy_data['Profile']);`

Comment: Hello Joe,
With the use your code the array key was removed, but gives data with two different array index. But want whole data in same array index.

Comment: Which one did you use? The array_values() or the foreach loop?

Comment: The problem with combining the two arrays is that in both arrays you have things with the key 'id' and things with the key 'created'. Unless you change the names of at least one of each of these, then you will end up overwriting values when you merge the two arrays.

Comment: Take a look the addition that I've made to the solution that I posted. I hope that what that accomplishes is what you are after and it a simple one liner.

Comment: No problem. What did you change in your query? If my solution was helpful, can you please mark it as a correct solution, or up-vote it? I suspect in your query all you needed to do was a JOIN between your two related tables.